# Aligning headers/footers using responsive styles

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, header, bigcartel

Check out [my site](http://www.rawpeaks.com) here to see the issue across different size screens and on mobile.

I originally used the Luna theme in Bigcartel, having modified parts to make it bespoke to our brand. Whilst doing so the Luna responsive theme no longer worked... having not changed it one bit (Something in my actual code must have caused it to stop working)...;it would just show a blank white screen (mobile).

I then copied and used the responsive style of a separate theme, which causes my site to act like the normal site on a mobile etc... however the headers/footers are all out of place and mis-sized. I have tried changing all widths to %, but have failed to notice any differences. I had managed to change the size of the flexslider.. so that now it works but I am struggling to change the size of the other major components on the page (including navigation bar).

I am reluctant to post any code in here as of yet... as I'm not sure what to include (I dont want to include all the responsive styles), but perhaps someone could point me in the right direction?

Thanks,

Comment: One way off fix it could be to add @media screen and (max-width: ...px) at some of the break points to re-align the images at the bottom and the headers nav.

Comment: What would be the best width to place them at? There are already '@media screen's in the responsive styles e.g. 
[/* sm */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px)]

Comment: When I scroll the page I notice a few break points where the bottom bar will go into the white area and the top navigation will hide behind the content. Here is a good online tool which might help you see what it will look like on different screen sizes which help help testing (http://quirktools.com/screenfly/#u=http%3A//www.rawpeaks.com&w=1366&h=768&a=1)

Comment: An example is at 900px (http://quirktools.com/screenfly/#u=http%3A//www.rawpeaks.com&w=900&h=600&s=1)

Comment: Great link, thanks, that will come in very handy.

Comment: So for each device size I just need to adjust the widths in the responsive styles so that they fit correctly?

Comment: You should only have to do it at a few points like 900px, and more some more where it messes up. Another way would be to use a framework such as bootstrap.